# Move database from 1.0.9 to 2.0.0

Tags: refinerycms

Had some problem with updating it from 1.0.9 , so I made a new project in 2.0.0 and now I just need to move the database. How do I do that ?

Comment: I've also had massive problems updating my RefineryCMS app.  Migrating the database and restoring my small amount of custom code seems like a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got answer on groups.google.com:
http://blog.craigambrose.com/past/2012/3/4/upgrading_to_refinery_cms_20/

Pete Higgins :"Craig Ambrose wrote an unofficial guide on upgrading Refinery 1.x to 2.0.x: http://blog.craigambrose.com/past/2012/3/4/upgrading_to_refinery_cms_20/

pete"

"I've got an upgrade guide at blog.craigambrose.com which includes a migration. Run the migration in your refinery 1 app then your db should be ready for you refinery 2 code base.

- Craig Ambrose"

Comment: Found the correct link: http://www.craigambrose.com/blog/2012/03/04/upgrading-to-refinery-cms-2-dot-0/

Comment: I just want to point out that, by default, database files are in .gitignore.  So if you're going to start messing with your database like this, be sure to track it or keep a backup.

Comment: You have to go through the web archive to get to this now: https://web.archive.org/web/20130728115939/http://www.craigambrose.com/blog/2012/03/04/upgrading-to-refinery-cms-2-dot-0/