# Move refinerycms database from 1.0.9 to 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, refinerycms

I want to move a refineryCMS 1.0.9 to 2. according to [Move database from 1.0.9 to 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683918/move-database-from-1-0-9-to-2-0-0) the best way to do it is to move database. But the info on how to do this is unavailible (broken link) www.craigambrose.com/blog/2012/03/04/upgrading-to-refinery-cms-2-dot-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog is down, but the original source is available at https://github.com/craigambrose/craigambrose.github.com/blob/master/blog/2012/03/04/upgrading-to-refinery-cms-2-dot-0/index.html

If you are on a mac/unix machine, you can access it locally as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/craigambrose/craigambrose.github.com
cd craigambrose.github.com/
open blog/2012/03/04/upgrading-to-refinery-cms-2-dot-0/index.html
```